# Tagging documents with predefined labels

Tags: indexing

I am working with large number of documents and have a set of predefined categories/tags(could be phrases) that would be present in the text of the documents either in the exact or inexact form. 
I want to assign each document to exactly one tag among the tags that is closest to its text.

Please give me some directions as to what should I do to address this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at the lucene search engine that tags the documents while indexing. Northernlight search engine used to do a similar task mentioned by you in their searching methodology. You can have a look at its implementation in order to get an idea.